# how to override ngx-quill editor link and make it open in the same tab? By default it opens in new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, quill

I am using quill rich editor with angular 4. Whenever I add a link it gets added with _target = "blank", which makes it open in a new tab. I want to open it in the same tab. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just remove the target attribute?

Comment: target attribute gets added when we use the link functionality. I don't have any way of accessing it.

Comment: I'm just guessing but maybe an absolute link will be to _blank and a relative one in the current window?

Comment: Actually, the absolute link and relative link both are opening in new window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The target attribute is set in the [link blot](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/formats/link.js).
You can [extend](https://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/#extending-blots) the link blot to remove this attribute:

```
var Link = Quill.import('formats/link');
class MyLink extends Link {
  static create(value) {
    const node = super.create(value);
    node.removeAttribute('target');
    return node;
  }
}
Quill.register(MyLink, true);

var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['link']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Ben, It worked. I want to add a toggle based on which I can decide whether to remove the "target" attribute or not. Is that possible, Please give suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to put that toggle button beside the "Save" button while adding the link.