# How to remove target attribute from a link vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quill

I am using https://quilljs.com/ editor it adds the target attribute to all links. I want to remove it all dynamically. I am using it in the SPA so it's not good.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do.

```
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[target]')
targets.forEach(e => {
    e.removeAttribute('target')
})
```

Comment: I am not using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52275503/6809056

You can extend the Link format and remove the target attribute.
See this [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QZMQzv).

```
var Link = Quill.import('formats/link');

class MyLink extends Link {
  static create(value) {
    const node = super.create(value);
    node.setAttribute('href', this.sanitize(value));
    //node.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    node.removeAttribute('target');
    return node;
  }
}

Quill.register(MyLink);


var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['link']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

Comment: I've seen this a number of times at different places in the past one hour but let's not pretend this is normal. Why do you have to do this ugly hack if you don't want your links open in new tabs? There's something seriously wrong with it even if it's probably a working solution.